# How to delete JMS Queue filestore

Tags: jboss, jms

I'm using Jboss Messaging with Jboss 4.2.2.GA. I have some problem with QUEUE, when i restart server, some persistent message will continue process. Now I want delete it but i don't know where it store ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-persistent queue....

Comment: But, currently i'm using persistent queue.

Comment: a persistent queue is going to keep messages across restarts of the JMS provider, so if you don't want that then use a non-persistent queue which will start with a clean slate on any restart.

Comment: That comment should really be a part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Data will be stored in **/server/default/data/hornetq/*.hq** file if you are using hornetQ